# ANGULAR - Loop thru ngFor checkboxes and count those that are checked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an ngFor for X number of checkboxes as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let child of childrenList; let indice=index">
    <p-checkbox label="{{child.firstname}} {{child.lastname}}" binary="true" (onChange)="dentalChanged(indice, $event)" name="item-{{indice}}">
    </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

I was able to identify when the item is checked, with the following code:

```
dentalChanged(indice: any, event: any): void {
  alert(indice)
  console.log(event.checked)
}
```

My problem is now, that I have to save the selected items when clicking a button, and since the number of elements on childrenList is variable, I dont know how to look from 0 to n.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SelectionModel, for example:

component

```
  selection = new SelectionModel<any[]>(true, []);
  items = [{ name: "checkbox1" }, { name: "checkbox2" }, { name: "checkbox3" }];
```

template

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}} - <mat-checkbox (change)="selection.toggle(item)"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(item)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>

  <div>
    Selection count: {{ selection.selected.length}}
  </div>
</div>
```

SelectionModel has many useful methods like toggle, deselect, isEmpty, clear and etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can store selected values in a variable

```
selectedValues: any[];

dentalChanged(indice: any, event: any, child: any): void {
  if (event.checked) {
    this.selectedValues.push(child);
  } else {
    // you can also use splice and indice to remove child if you dont have any unique property like id
    this.selectedValues = this.selectedValues.filter(c => c.id != child.id);
  }
}
```

pass child to dentalChanged method from html

```
<div *ngFor="let child of childrenList; let indice=index">
    <p-checkbox label="{{child.firstname}} {{child.lastname}}" binary="true" (onChange)="dentalChanged(indice, $event. child)" name="item-{{indice}}">
    </p-checkbox>
</div>
```